# NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Rails 3.2.1 and try to install devise (1.1.rc0) with ubuntu

My rake routes give me

```
new GET    /users/registration/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new 

config/routes.rb
DeviseApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  match "users/registration/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
  resources :projects
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

when http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/registration/sign_up
I take
undefined method `user_registration_path' for Class

Gemfile
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise', '1.1.rc0'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I follow instructions from episode 209 Introducing Devise Railscasts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the route as a [named route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) if you want to use `user_registration_path`

```
match "users/registration/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new", :as => 'user_registration'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, fixed the NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new but continues and say ArgumentError in Devise/registrations#new wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Comment: @Παναγιώτης Πετρίδης : look at the stack trace in your console, it indicates which line and which function is misused

Comment: unfortunately I do not understand Maybe stack trace is like this?                                       tic.rb:53:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was to change the Gemfile. New Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

Maybe the combination rails '3.2.1' and devise '1.1.rc0' was catastrophic for me.